# ColdFusion Append to Array for JSON

Tags: arrays, json, coldfusion

I'm trying to convert some code and found myself stuck in the proper way to add to an array that has items in it.  How do I properly add this set of data to the list_items of the array.  My issues is with the line of code before closing the Loop...

```
<cfset data["item_list"] = [] />
<cfloop query="qryShoppingCartContents">
    <cfset items = {
       "name" = "#qryShoppingCartContents.name#",
       "description" = "#qryShoppingCartContents.short_desc#",
       "quantity" = "#myqty#",
       "price" = "$#numberformat(qryShoppingCartContents.retail_price)#"
     } />

     <cfset arrayAppend(item_list, items) />
</cfloop>
```

Comment: You are referencing your array incorrectly (unless that is just a typo here). Within the loop you have `<cfset arrayAppend(item_list, items) />` but your array is being defined as part of a structure named "data" `data["item_list"]`. It should work if you change it to `<cfset arrayAppend(data["item_list"], items) />`.

Comment: Thank you!  I wasn't 100% sure that would work with the arrayAppend command - but it did!

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it worked for you. That will make it easier for others finding this post in the future to see it.

Answer (score 1):

*Promoted from the comments*

The only issue I see is that you are referencing the array incorrectly within the loop. You have declared your array as part of a structure named "data" with this line:

```
<cfset data["item_list"] = [] />
```

But within the loop you are attempting to reference the array as only "item_list" in this line:

```
<cfset arrayAppend(item_list, items) />
```

It should work if you change that line to reference the array as part of the "data" structure like this:

```
<cfset arrayAppend(data["item_list"], items) />
```

Or by using dot notation like this:

```
<cfset arrayAppend(data.item_list, items) />
```